# How to mock Thread.sleep?

Tags: mockito, quarkus

In my implementation I have to wait 5 seconds when an exception is thrown for retry.

In test I want to avoid waiting 5 seconds.

Is it possible to mock it in Quarkus or Mockito ? `Thread.sleep(5000)`

Comment: Easily, just don't use Thread.sleep. Use your own Sleeper instead with a SleeperProvider that is different in the test code. If the sleep is hidden in framework code that you cannot modify and directly calls Thread.sleep, then probably not.

Answer (score 2):

As ewramner suggests (assuming you are using Spring, and ignoring exceptions):

```
interface Sleeper {
  void sleep(int ms);
}
```

In your application:

```
@Component
public class SleeperImpl {
  void sleep(int ms) {
    Thread.sleep(ms);
  }
}

@Component MyClassThatRetries {
  private final Sleeper sleeper;
  ...
  public MyClassThatRetries (Sleeper sleeper, ...) {
    this.sleeper = sleeper;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

In your unit test:

```
class MyTest {
  public void test() {
    Sleeper sleeper = mock(Sleeper.class);
    MyClassThatRetries myClass = new MyClassThatRetries(sleeper, ... );
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocking of `Thread.sleep()` (as well as mocking `static` class methods in general) is possible with PowerMockito.

Please see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770495/21384216

Comment: Does PowerMockito work with Quarkus? I haven't tried, but we had significant problems upgrading a few projects to Java 17 and had to switch to regular Mockito.